# Beamer rotated text in right margin

Tags: beamer

I would like to add some text to the right margin in beamer. Tried using packages "background" and "eso-pic", but they aren't doing the job. I need to specify the color of the text block, the width and the height.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal, yet complete, example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way with tikz:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[draw=red,fill=yellow,rectangle,shift={(-0.5,0)},
  text width=3cm,above,rotate=90] at (current page.east) {\color{black}\footnotesize SOME TEXT that will be broken in several lines};\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: broken=split :P

Comment: This works. Thanks.

Comment: @user37222 ... Welcome ... You may accept the answer if you wish to (by clicking the tick "button " next to the question), or wait for another answer too (in case that someone will provide a better one ... but you could also change the accepted answer afterwords)